# CUDA : Driver version is insufficient for CUDA runtime

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, cuda

When running the CUDA example `/usr/local/cuda/samples/1_Utilities/deviceQuery$` with the `sudo ./deviceQuery` command, the output was :

```
 ./deviceQuery Starting...
 CUDA Device Query (Runtime API) version (CUDART static linking)
cudaGetDeviceCount returned 35
-> CUDA driver version is insufficient for CUDA runtime version
Result = FAIL
```

On using the `lspci -v | grep -i` command I get :

```
NVIDIA Corporation GF117M [GeForce 610M/710M/820M / GT 620M/625M/630M/720M] (rev a1)
```

The `lshw -c video` command gives :

```
PCI (sysfs)  


  *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 0b
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:63 memory:b5000000-b53fffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff     ioport:6000(size=64)
  *-display
       description: 3D controller
       product: GF117M [GeForce 610M/710M/820M / GT 620M/625M/630M/720M]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:09:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=nouveau latency=0
       resources: irq:62 memory:b3000000-b3ffffff memory:a0000000-afffffff memory:b0000000-b1ffffff ioport:3000(size=128)
```

So might it be that CUDA doesn't work because the i915 driver is in play instead of the nvidia one ?
If so how do I get this working ?

The last guide I followed to install the nvidia drivers really messed up my system and it needed a reinstall, please suggest a guide that works well for Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 2):

You appear to be using a laptop. Usually, after the Nvidia drivers are installed, the Intel GPU is used by default to conserve power. However, you can run any program with the Nvidia GPU by running it with `optirun`:

```
optirun ./deviceQuery
```

or

```
sudo optirun ./deviceQuery
```

though I don't think you'd need `sudo` for CUDA samples

Edit: As pointed out by [Pilot6](https://askubuntu.com/users/167850/pilot6), `optirun` is available through the `bumblebee` package in Ubuntu. Check the project's [website](http://bumblebee-project.org/) for more details.

Comment: sudo: optirun: command not found

Comment: @MeghdeepRay This is a bumblebee command.

Comment: `sudo optirun` working not not `optirun` alone, any idea why I need root permissions and how can I change that?